# RewriteRule forwarding only if QUERY_STRING or REQUEST_URI are not empty

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I would like to have a `RewriteRule` that forwarding any url call with `QUERY_STRING` or `REQUEST_URI` to another website and ignore any other calls.

For example:

```
http://X.com/images  >> http://Y.com/images
http://X.com/?action=show  >> http://Y.com/?action=show
http://X.com/  >> http://X.com/ // Or Ignore
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect /?querystring to http://y.com/?querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^$ http://y.com/ [L,R]
#/anyUri to http://y.com/anyUri but exclude the root
RewriteRule ^.+ http://y.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am targeting any QUERY_STRING and REQUEST_URI

Comment: Great that was helpful.. Thank you 

just minor correction needed {REQUEST_URI] >> {REQUEST_URI}

Answer (score 0):

The `QUERY_STRING` is part of `REQUEST_URI` parameter. You just need to check for existence of the latter:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?x\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://y.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you 

I believe you mean HTTP_HOST not HTT_HOST

it works with
http://X.com/images  >> http://Y.com/images

But not with
http://X.com/?action=show  >> http://Y.com/?action=show

But it works with 
http://X.com/index.php?action=show  >> http://Y.com/index.php?action=show

Comment: @ZuhairAli Yeah. Typo fixed. Also added a QSA flag so that a single rule can handle all cases.